# ksoap2: Parsing complex SoapObject- How to prevent this hashmap from being overwritten?

Tags: java, android, parsing, recursion, ksoap2

I am writing the following method to *recursively* parse `XML` data contained a *complex* `SoapObject` (*that is a `SoapObject` which has `SoapObject` as a value of some properties*). The SoapObject is the response from a SOAP based web service, which I consumed using `ksoap2`

**In this method**, we iterate through all the properties of the passed-in response SoapObject. We check if the property is NOT a `SoapObject` (which means it has a simple `String` name and a `String` value), in which case we simply put the name and value into a `HashMap` as a key-value pair. But if the property IS a `SoapObject`, we call the method itself (recursive) and pass it this very `SoapObject`...

**CODE:**

```
static protected Map<String, String> parseComplexSoapObject(SoapObject soapObject) {
        Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        //Iterate through the properties starting at top of soapObject
        for (int i=0; i<soapObject.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

            //Get the current property
            Object currentPropertyObject = soapObject.getProperty(i);

            //If current property is the last property, check if it is a string or a soap object
            if (i==soapObject.getPropertyCount()-1) {
                //If it is a string, add the key value pair of property to the map and break the loop. The only statement after the loop will return the map. 
                if(currentPropertyObject!=null && !(currentPropertyObject instanceof SoapObject)) {
                    hashMap.put(currentPropertyObject.toString(), currentPropertyObject.toString());
                    break;
                }
                //else If it is a soap object, cast the currentPropertyObject to SoapObject and make a recursive call to the function itself, passing the current property so that the method gets "inside" this current property soap object and does all this again
                else if(currentPropertyObject!=null && currentPropertyObject.getClass().equals(SoapObject.class)) {
                    SoapObject currentPropertySoapObject = (SoapObject) currentPropertyObject;
                    parseComplexSoapObject(currentPropertySoapObject);
                }
            }
            //else if the current property not the last property, check if it is a soap object or a string
            else {
                //if the current property is a string, add its key value pair to the string  and "continue" the loop, so that the loop continues to read the next properties
                if(currentPropertyObject!=null && !(currentPropertyObject instanceof SoapObject)) {
                    hashMap.put(currentPropertyObject.toString(), currentPropertyObject.toString());
                    continue;
                }
                //else if the current property is a soap object, cast the currentPropertyObject to SoapObject and make a recursive call to the function itself, passing the current property so that the method gets "inside" this current property soap object and does all this again
                else if(currentPropertyObject!=null && currentPropertyObject.getClass().equals(SoapObject.class)) {
                    SoapObject currentPropertySoapObject = (SoapObject) currentPropertyObject;
                    parseComplexSoapObject(currentPropertySoapObject);
                }
            }
        }

        return hashMap;
    }
```

**PROBLEMS:**

1. Now, the problem is that the `HashMap` the method returns is created inside this method, so each time the method is recursively called, the `HashMap` is recreated and the previous data is lost.
2. Even if I create the `HashMap` outside this method and simple write data to it from the method, the problem will be that there will be no distinction as in which name value pairs have come from which level of nesting (e.g.

   ```
   <result>
     <id>25323205</id>
     <name>Cric</name>
   <result>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <result>
     <id>445</id>
   </result>
   ```

will be stored like `HashMap = {id=>25323205, name=>Cric, version=>1.0, id=>445}`. I would rather like it this way:

```
HashMap = {result=>{id=>25323205, name=>Cric}, version=>1.0, result=>{id=>445}}
```

So what can I do about this?

Comment: create a `List<HashMap<?,?>` and add in all your hashmap's inside it!

Comment: do you think to create a class called result and assign id and name as attributes for this class ???????

Comment: i suggest you to create class named it 'result' and assign to this class the attributes (id and name) than use the Gson library, the Gson library give you the ability to convert from/to json to/from java object ..... if this help you leave me a comment to put it as answer ... best regards

Comment: @BinaryMan It is a good idea, but please see the example in the question. I also have properties with simple string values, like `version` in the example given. What will I do about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is, that You trying converting multidimensional data into flat structure. It's posible only sometimes under some circumstances. Think if it's really posible for Your data and business needs.
I have some ideas what You may do - any may be enought and every useless :)

1. If multiplication of names is always on different levels of nesting - try to use full name from "body" fe. "result/id", "result/something/id".
2. You can number similiar tags fe. "id>001", "id>002" or something (needed second map - of ints). Its the way that allows You storing, but slows You down much on reading, searching etc. If Your later just traverse data from beginning to end it will be just enought.
3. If You need to isolate Your code from ksoap data model, You may try to project SoapObject/Primitive stucture to such built with standard Java objects, but of same complexity and no information lost. This structure for xml will be list of lists.

Here is example class Elem that may hold Name+Value, where value may be Object.That Object will be ArrayList or just String. And the simple method that translates Soap... to new structure:

```
class Elem{
    String name;
    Object value;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

List<Elem> parseComplexSoapObject(SoapObject soapObject) {
    List<Elem> tmp=new ArrayList<Elem>();
    PropertyInfo info=new PropertyInfo();

    for (int i=0; i<soapObject.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
        Object currentPropertyObject = soapObject.getProperty(i);

        Elem newElem = new Elem();
        if(currentPropertyObject instanceof SoapObject){
            SoapObject currentPropertySoapObject = (SoapObject)currentPropertyObject;
            info.clear();
            soapObject.getPropertyInfo(i, info);
            newElem.setName(info.name);
            newElem.setValue(parseComplexSoapObject(currentPropertySoapObject));
        }else{
            //assume primitive
            SoapPrimitive currentPropertySoapPrimitive = (SoapPrimitive)currentPropertyObject;
            info.clear();
            soapObject.getPropertyInfo(i, info);
            newElem.setName(info.name);
            newElem.setValue(currentPropertySoapPrimitive.getValue().toString());
        }
        tmp.add(newElem);
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as we have discussed in comments under your question post, so I suggest you to use the [Gson library](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-parse-json-to-java.jsp).

We decided to use the Google JSON library ***GSON*** to **parse the JSON response stream to the specific Java class** seamlessly.

The Google json - gson is an open source java api for parsing and building json. It has extensive support for java generics. It also provides support for converting third party classes to json. It can be used to serialize and deserialize complex objects with deep hierarchies that may contain generic classes.

In a nutshell, create a class and name it "result", add attributes ( like: name, id, version ...), and note that in Gson library you can use the **arrays** (**collections**), so you can create an attribute in the class result with type of collection (collection of result !), and also you can use a 'result' as attribut in the class result !!!!

You dont know how much tricks can the Gson library give to you to play with data ....

Trust me that the "Gson Library" is the *backbone* of the solution to your topic.
Regards !

Comment: Why do you think I have `JSON` data? It is `XML` contained in a `SoapObject`!

Comment: great, try to convert your XML to JSON, than you can use the Gson library easly :)

Comment: Convert XML to JSON just to use a library for parsing, seems like not-a-good-practice to me :s